# How can I create a sub-index for rows in a SQL table sharing the same ID ordered by date

Tags: sql, alter

I have a table where each row has columns for item IDs and dates. Id like to be able to add an additional column that will index each row sharing an ID by their date. For example, I have table 1, how to I get table 2?

Table 1:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/2/2022 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 |
| 1 | 12/18/2021 |
| 2 | 11/22/2021 |
| 3 | 10/6/2021 |
| 2 | 8/13/2021 |

Table 2:

| ID | Date | IDX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/2/2022 | 3 |
| 1 | 12/18/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 11/22/2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 10/6/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 8/13/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/1/2022 | 3 |

Comment: Why does (1, 3/2) have IDX = 3?

Comment: Submitting usable data will motivate people helping you. The dates in your examples are simply not even dates. Also please explain the rule; people can't guess what is in your mind when you said 'index each row'?

Comment: Simply not a clue what you are asking here. Those aren't dates, they're fractions. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a *clear description*.

Comment: Provided year since apparently month/day doesnt make sense to people

Comment: That's just a minor problem. We still don't understand how to get the IDX values.

Comment: Nor why the rows are ordered as such.

Comment: The idx is ordered by earliest date for rows sharing an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what kind of SQL you're using. If you can use `RANK()` can do what you are needing.

> ```
> create table s (
>  id int,
>  dat date);
> insert into s values
> (1,'2020-01-01'),
> (2,'2020-01-02'),
> (1,'2020-01-03'),
> (2,'2020-01-04'),
> (3,'2020-01-05'),
> (2,'2020-01-06');
> ```

> ```
> select
>   id,
>   dat "date",
>   rank() over 
>     (partition by id
>      order by dat) ranking
> from s
> order by id, dat;
> ```

> ```
> id | date       | ranking
> -: | :--------- | ------:
>  1 | 2020-01-01 |       1
>  1 | 2020-01-03 |       2
>  2 | 2020-01-02 |       1
>  2 | 2020-01-04 |       2
>  2 | 2020-01-06 |       3
>  3 | 2020-01-05 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cdfa2552e36eaabd3d05559c1a28c5a9)*